# Adjust the sensor to the position of the phone

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I have developed a method that gives me perfectly the angle of inclination of the telephone. Start counting from the 0 value when it is straight and I would like to have the phone in hand and adjust that 0 to the position of the phone.

¿How can I do this "adjust"?

[image: The problem]

And here my code:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            mags = lowPassFilter(event.values.clone(), mags);
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            accels = lowPassFilter(event.values.clone(), accels);
            break;
    }

    if (mags != null && accels != null) {
        Rot = new float[9];
        I = new float[9];
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(Rot, I, accels, mags);

        float[] outR = new float[9];
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(Rot, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, outR);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(outR, values);


        roll = Math.round(values[2] * 57.2957795f); --> I WANT TO CORRECT THIS
        //azimuth = Math.round(values[1] * 57.2957795f);
        pitch = Math.round(values[0] * 57.2957795f); --> I WANT TO CORRECT THIS


        mags = null;
        accels = null;



    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

I try to do this changes but isn't working

After this:

```
roll = Math.round(values[2] * 57.2957795f); --> I WANT TO CORRECT THIS
        //azimuth = Math.round(values[1] * 57.2957795f);
        pitch = Math.round(values[0] * 57.2957795f); --> I WANT TO CORRECT THIS
```

And the button code:

```
public void adjustSensor(View view) {
    if(roll > 0){
        correctRoll = roll;
    }else{
        correctRoll = Math.abs(roll);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the angle when they hit the button.  When calculating the angle, subtract the saved value from the calculated one.  If that answer is <0, add 360 (to its always between 0 and 360 degrees).  The default stored angle should be 0.

Do this with both angles you care about (in two different variables).

Comment: The angle isn't between 0 to 360 is between 0 to 90 and 0 to -90 so i can't use this solution

Comment: No, it's geometry. It's a math problem.

Comment: So if it's a Math problem you know the solution?

Comment: I already told it to you. If you're ok with negative angles, just don't do the add 360 part of my original answer.

Comment: I try this:if(roll > 0){
            correctRoll = roll;
        }else{
            correctRoll = Math.abs(roll);
        }  and i add this on "onSensorChange": pitch = pitch - correctPitch;
            roll = roll - correctRoll;      but  isn't working

Comment: I edited first post, what you think I'm doing wrong?